# How can I narrow down a class with an id in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the div:

```
<div class="io-content-pane" id="record-view" style="position: relative;></div>
```

How can I select this based on its class and its id in jQuery?

Comment: You'd better read [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Shouldn't the id be unique?

Comment: Also you are missing a closing quote for the style attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ids are unique in the page, so all you need is this:

```
$("#record-view")
```

If you want to combine an id and a class (which there should be no reason to do because it doesn't select anything different in your page and is likely slower to process), you would do it like this:

```
$("#record-view.io-content-pane")
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the ID should suffice since the ID **is REQUIRED to be unique in an HTML document**.

So, that said, `jQuery('#record-view')` should suffice.

However, to answer your question:

```
jQuery('#record-view.io-content-pane');
```

Again, note that IDs must be unique. If you have non-unique IDs, your page isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Other way around, choose the class from an ID.

```
$("#record-view.io-content-pane")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#record-view.io-content-pane");
```

But i wonder why you will need both, because an ID is supposed to be unique.

So what i suggesst is to create different ids for elements and if they are related, give them the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the id, so it is simply `$("#record-view")`